# Identityserver 5 security updates

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am developing a solution for a client which needs enterprise-grade IDP. Since the solution is in .net 5.0, I am thinking of using identity server 5.0 as one possible option. Our main concern is that if we use identity server 5.0 then who is responsible for providing security updates for the server? is it duende software? what if duende software is not there few years from now?

Comment: What if Microsoft stops updating windows or .net?

Comment: Microsoft is a publicly listed strong company with 181K employees with billions in balance sheet....and duende software is a startup with less than 5 employees...what point you are trying to make? Nothing against startups in general or Duende software but concern of my client will be valid from LTS point of view

Comment: My point is that is out of your control and will always be a valid concern for any software that you use and it's a risk factor that you need to accept or find another solution to your problem. I'm not sure Stackoverflow is a proper place to ask the future of said company

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.